# Proxy-address-forwarding property from Thorntail to Quarkus

Tags: reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, quarkus, thorntail

in my previous implementation using Thorntail I have used this property to manage the request behind the Proxy (nginx):

```
thorntail.undertow.servers.default-servers.http-listeners.default.proxy-address-forwarding = true
```

Which is the right property to use in Quarkus ?

From the documentation I have found out the following one but in my case it doesn't work:

```
quarkus.http.proxy.proxy-address-forwarding = true
```

Thanks

Comment: For the moment I have created a Filter to manage the request behind the proxy

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the Quarkus version from `1.7.3-Final` to `1.9.2-Final` and added these two properties:

```
quarkus.http.proxy.proxy-address-forwarding = true
quarkus.http.proxy.enable-forwarded-host = true
```

It works!